# iOS application Rejection

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I publish an ios app to apps store, but they rejected the app and suggested for distributing as in house app, due to my app doesn't have any signup but login And they treated it as in house app for employees. The business requirement is the login credentials is generated if the user (not the employee) takes the service of the company then only they get credential to access the app, Thus the app needs to be on the app store (where in house distribution cannot). In this case, what should I do? (I read their Policy pages and especially their mentioned section **3.2 Other Business Model Issues** where **3.2.2 unacceptable** but none of them fit with my case.)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You've answered your own question here. Your app has no sign in, a random user in the wild can download your app but they can't use it because you haven't provided them any way of getting a credential for the app. Apple have suggested that you could distribute it internally, this way only the people who need the app can access it. You would need an enterprise developer license to distribute this way or go off the grid and for every new phone that needs to use the app, rebuild the app with that phone on your developer profile (thats hacky and doesnt scale at all).

Comment: in this situation you can provide a sample access to them for checking. When app published then you can remove the access.

Comment: well i agreed, but the app has to be promoted from online, for example it'll be a manual process like the app got web portal and *download app from app store button* lets say the users can quick download the app and login with the credentials - should i request this use case to that required the app to be published onto app store

Comment: Not like that. Basically in one point if your app need login to go next then you have to provide login credentials for checking purpose.